# MySQL FULLTEXT Not Working In Production Environment

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

My dev/production MySQL versions and data are nearly identical. I'm using MySQL 5.6 with InnoDB tables in both with the exact same configs, data, table structure and keys.

To be precise, there is a slight difference in the MySQL version. My production version is 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 and my dev version is 5.6.17 running off WAMP Server though I've not found any documentation or anything in the MySQL change logs that would suggest this is the issue.

Here is an example query:

```
select title, match(title) against ('+banquet* +runner*' in boolean mode) as match_score from jobs order by match_score desc limit 1
```

In dev it returns one row, in production it returns nothing. I can confirm the record exists because if I were to run this query in production, I would get the expected result:

```
select title from jobs where title='banquet runner'
```

A similar query, which does return results but far fewer than expected:

```
select title, match(title) against ('+front +desk +clerk' in boolean mode) as match_score from jobs where having match_score >= 1 order by match_score desc
```

In dev I get 95 results. In production I get 49.

As stated I've confirmed the data is the same and indexes are identical. I've also confirmed all the configs are the same by running:

```
show variables like '%_ft_%'
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would not trust `match_score >= 1` to be consistent.

Comment: My instinct says your InnoDB fulltext indexes could be subtly tainted by nonsensical behavior in any prior version of MySQL Server that has run on the machine, or by any fulltext configuration that was different between now and the time the tables were created... and dropping the indexes and re-creating them would be the next step to try, particularly if either server has ever had a version upgrade or config changes of this nature.

Comment: MIchael, thank you for the quick fix. This was exactly the problem. Just needed to drop the FT index and recreate it. Thanks also for the details on the possible cause. I've not touched the FT configs, neither has the server been upgraded since the index creation, so I'll keep an eye on future events to see what may've corrupted the index.